# Word prediction engine

Tags: android

I'm looking to build a client similar to android 4.1's word prediction. I already built out all the code for the engine to take in any type of text file and parse it in order to use those sentences for reference in predictions.

I plan on using the user's SMS conversations as reference but I also need some sort of base text file to use initially. Any ideas on a good text conversation source to parse and make word predictions from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply grab twitters sample stream, make a simple language filter and store the text data. Tweets are textually similar to SMS and the twitter API is easy to learn.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public